# How to remove the div surrounding the view block?

Tags: views, 8

I created a view block that I added in the navigation bar.

[image]

When I inspect my page, I have a div around my block.

How can I delete this div ?

I want to have only :

```
<section class="views-element-container block block-views block-views-blockmenu-page-utilisateur-block-2 clearfix" id="block-views-block-menu-page-utilisateur-block-2">
```

[image]

Comment: Did you enable Twig Debug on your site? If yes, you'll see the current template used for this HTML. Once you know the template used, find a hook that preprocesses the output.

Answer (score 0):

- Enable Twig debugging as per this https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates
- Then, see which template file is currently outputting your block view
- Create a new twig template file in your theme with the same name
- Copy the content of the original file
- Edit accordingly